# BLS signatures and the Splitting Zero attack

Tags: security, signature, cryptography

In 2021 security researcher Quan Thoi Minh Nguyen published two papers ("0" and "Attacks and weaknesses of BLS aggregate signatures") where he highlighted some security weaknesses of BLS signatures.

Broadly speaking, the two main security issues he exposed are:

1. the "consensus attack"
2. the "splitting zero attack"

While I found discussions about mitigating the consensus attack through the usage of batch verification (https://ethresear.ch/t/fast-verification-of-multiple-bls-signatures/5407), I did not find any discussion about the splitting zero attack in the context of Ethereum.

Therefore my question is: Does Ethereum address the attack somehow? Or did the developers just determine that the attack is not a threat to Ethereum?